# Spring hibernate template when to use and why?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Greetings,
Currently developing small web service application where response from web service (using CXF + Spring) processed and saved to database. To work with database I am using Hibernate(3.5). Browsing some Hibernate + Spring example on web, I often can see the usage of HibernateTemplate so I am a bit confused about this moment and wanted to ask:

Do you use HibernateTemplate in your Hibernate3 applications? 
When does HibernateTemplate can make your development life better and based on what points can I decide do I need to use it or not ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

All spring templates (hibernate, jdbc, rest, jpa etc.) have the same pros and cons:

**Pro:** They perform common setup routines for you, let you skip the boilerplate and concentrate on the logic you want.

**Con:** you are coupling your application tightly to the spring framework. For this reason, Spring recommends that `HibernateTemplate` no longer be used.

Specifically, what `HibernateTemplate` did for you was to automatically open and close sessions and commit or rollback transactions after your code executed. However, all of this can be achieved in an aspect-oriented way using Spring's [Declarative Transaction Management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative).

**Reference:**

- Spring Reference: [ORM: Hibernate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) for the current suggested Spring Hibernate usage patterns
- Spring Reference: [Classic Spring Usage: HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html#orm-hibernate-template)

---

**Update:**

As of Spring 3.1 (and newer versions), [`HibernateTemplate` has been removed](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096). See [Hibernate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate) for the currently suggested usage patterns.

Comment: Thank you for links and for mention that HibernateTemplate is not recommended way now, I guess I will go with Declarative Transaction way.

Comment: Good Idea. The template approach is still valid for REST, JMS, LDAP and possibly others, but for ORM, the transactional approach is more powerful and also easier.

Comment: With Spring 3.1's Hibernate 4 support, the HibernateTemplate is no longer simply "not recommended"; it has been eliminated entirely. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8096

Comment: On going template less by Alef Arendsen on official Spring blog
http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/

[Spring tries to be non-invasive, this is another great example!]

Comment: Correct url: http://spring.io/blog/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-spring-s-hibernatetemplate-and-or-jpatemplate

Comment: @JianChen perhaps at some point you want to use a different persistence provider and / or a different IOC container. Techniques like the ones mentioned here make sure you only have to rewrite a small isolated part of your application. This may save you weeks or months in a large project. Read "Clean Code", specifically the chapter "Boundaries" about the benefits of this approach.

Comment: @JianChen true. for small projects it's fine to tightly couple everything together. But you need to be prepared to throw everything away and start from scratch when requirements change. seen it more than once. YAGNI can either save you weeks of work now or cost you months later. I've seen both happen

Comment: Hello friends, May I know which framework or technology is being used under Data Layer in Java based applications nowadays?

Comment: @ArunRaaj that's impossible to answer. All of them, really. If you are using Spring, then [Spring Data](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data) is a common approach for many persistence technologies. I'd start there.

Answer (score 11):

Let me clarify one thing that Spring's HibernateTemplate will not be supported going forward, that means Hibernate 4+ versions do not support HibernateTemplate. So it is advised to use [declarative transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative) as suggested by Sean.

Comment: See this when you're reading Duffy's recommendation of HibernateTemplate, BTW. It's not even supported any more.

Comment: Anyone reading this should note that it came TWO YEARS after my original answer. Clairvoyance isn't in my toolbox.

Answer (score 5):

HibernateTemplate encapsulates a number of things for you to make your life easier.

It's your choice to use it or not.  For that matter, you can work with a database without Hibernate.  Spring's JDBC stuff is very good.  You might find it easier to get your problem done without having to learn Hibernate.

Comment: Medium- to long-term, using Hibernate is much smarter & more productive. Following the above answer's advance would be dangerous. I recommend learning & using Hibernate.

Comment: Dangerous?  Ridiculous.  I think the above comment is hilarious.  I recommend using the right tool for the job.

Comment: Plenty of projects have been started 'just using JDBC, because it's simpler'. Yet should have been started with Hibernate, because after 2 weeks it would have been more efficient.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job -- & follow a hint, as to what the right tool is.

Comment: Not in my experience.  Hibernate is for people who can't write decent SQL.  You'll notice, Thomas, that this question is more than two years old.  Why are you riding this Hibernate hobby horse so hard?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSessionInViewFilter pattern is effective. This opens a Hibernate session  & binds it to your thread, during the processing of every request. OpenSessionInView also extends the Session and loadability to View rendering & the View layer, which decreases coupling & complexity (by enabling that to 'just work').

My philosophies don't really agree with aspect-based/ declarative transaction management. I like to make major state-change/ lifecycle events 'explicit', since they should be absolutely definite -- not weakly dependent on multiple hidden & indirect layers, which may or may not work.

It provides a point to debug at.

TX commit is only one line of code; but it's the major one you want to breakpoint on. No longer syntactically, than a 'transactional' declaration; but a hell of a lot more definite.

Frankly I find "user commands" or "requests", which are the proper place to initiate a transaction & control transactionality from, should be well-structured, well-identified & fairly explicit within the application.

*(I did have trouble getting the aspect class-loading stuff to work, trying it when it first came out. My assessment is that compared to well-written OO code, aspect has only limited marginal value.)*

**Tip:  I generally make a helper class, to make it *really* convenient to get the Session & to commit the Transaction.**

HbHelper or somesuch.

Comment: -1 for the utter nonsense expressed in "not weakly dependent on airy fairy magic layers, which may or may not work"

Comment: Let me know when you can place a breakpoint on your commit, @duffymo. You can also tell the kids *how you'd even start to debug this.. when things didn't work perfectly*. And perhaps you'd also like to explain how declarative syntax is 'shorter' than writing `HbHelper.commit()'`.

Comment: Don't get me wrong -- there can be arguments in favour of this technology. But, I like to weigh actual pros & cons. And explicit code, is definitively more reliable & more debuggable. You'd be a fool to think otherwise.

Comment: Not really.  I'm not a fool, and I don't use Hibernate.

Comment: As far as the debuggable comment goes, I can put a breakpoint in any code in my project with IntelliJ.  That includes every Spring class; ergo, a breakpoint in the aspect that implements the annotation.  You just have to have some understanding of exactly what's going on.  Fortunately I do.

Comment: I've had the source linked for Spring, Hibernate, ANTLR, Tomcat, JBoss, and HttpUnit for years (and rather a few more projects, beyond those). The issue is not just visibility -- it's selectivity, if you understand database terminology. Explicit code executes at that time only, and is 100% selective. Implicit code is called from all over the place, and thus has very poor selectivity. To put it in database terms, you're the man using a table with no index.

Comment: I understand database terminology.  I consider this your opinion, nothing more.

Comment: Can you be a little more polite and maybe just not carry on this discussion from a year ago without actually discussing anything? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks minitech.. exactly.

Answer (score 1):

All the templates will be deprecated going forward. Better to use entity manager which is JPA's standard.