# best practices for hibernate 3.6 and spring 3?

Tags: hibernate, spring

any good examples of integrating the latest versions of hibernate and spring? template pros and cons?

Comment: Apparently hambone really doesn't want this question asked.

Comment: I disagree. He is looking for some guidance to get started on latest spring and hibernate versions. He also wanted to know the pros and cons of using HibernateTemplace provided by spring-dao.

Comment: @Pangea: He is also repeatedly defacing his own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking more documentation than the one provided [here from spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate)?

Here are the pros and cons of using a hibernate template: [Spring hibernate template when to use and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067775/spring-hibernate-template-when-to-use-and-why)

Comment: thanks pangea! those links are perfect