# Best Practices for Integrating Hibernate 3.6 and Spring Framework 3?

Tags: hibernate, spring

Let me try this again since the first post got mangled... I've seen a few different methods for integrating Spring and Hibernate... What are the best practices for integrating the latest versions of Hibernate and Spring? What are the pros and cons to using the Spring Hibernate template? Any examples would be cool. Thx!

Comment: possible duplicate of [best practices for hibernate 3.6 and spring 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496521/best-practices-for-hibernate-3-6-and-spring-3)

Comment: michael, something happened to that post.. the markup was mangled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking more documentation than the one provided [here from spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate)?

Here are the pros and cons of using a hibernate template: [Spring hibernate template when to use and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067775/spring-hibernate-template-when-to-use-and-why)

[Here](http://www.springbyexample.org/) you can get more examples with explanations.