# Hibernate Template Query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Hibernate Template to store and get data from my database. I am trying to check if the user already exists in database or not. What I have tried is

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findUser(Integer socialId) {
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.validatedId = ?";
        return hibernateTemplate.find(queryString, socialId);
    }
}
```

but it says **Type mismatch: cannot convert from List < capture#2-of ? > to List< User >**

Thanks

Comment: First you need to read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002768/why-hibernatetemplate-isnt-recommended

Why using hibernatetemplate isn't recommended
Or you can read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/hibernatedaosupport-is-not-recommended-why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
FROM User u WHERE u.validatedId = ?
```

Also you need to type cast to `List<User>` since `HibernateTemplate.find` simple returns `List` with no generics.

Comment: Changing the query does not remove the error it says you need to cast to List <User>

Comment: Does it not work when you cast? You need to cast since find does not use generics

Comment: Not tested but when I cast it gives warning Type safety warning

Comment: There is no way you can avoid the casting and the type warning, since HibernateTemplate.find simply returns List, not List<T>. Please try it out and let me know

Comment: the app is not running bcz of some ip restrictions I will check it in home and will let you know

Comment: @UmairIqbal Ok, no problem

Comment: It gives the following error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: users is not mapped [FROM users u WHERE u.validatedId = ?] . May table name is users

Answer (score 0):

return (List<User>)(List<?>)hibernateTemplate.find(queryString, socialId);