# Can't Create Transaction [Spring Boot + Hibernate]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception, sessionfactory

I stuck with Hibernate Session Problem.
Problem occurs when i try to run query like

```
getHibernateTemplate().find("from ApplicationConfiguration where type = ? and key = ?", type, key);
```

Spring boot logs show that hibernate successfully found tables in a base package.
This is my configuration

```
package com.project.name;


import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.project.name")
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties"})
public class PersistenceConfiguration {


    //HIBERNATE
    private static final String HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";
    private static final String SCHEMA_STRATEGY = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String HIBERNATE_MAPPING_CLASSPATH = "com/project/name/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    private static final String NEW_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS = "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings";
    private static final String IDENTIFIER_ROLLBACK = "hibernate.use_identifier_rollback";
    private final String BASE_PACKAGE = "com.project.name.domain";

    //C3P0
    private final String C3P0_MAX_SIZE = "c3p0.max_size";
    private final String C3P0_MIN_SIZE = "c3p0.min_size";
    private final String C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT = "c3p0.acquire_increment";
    private final String C3P0_IDLE_TEST_PERIOD = "c3p0.idle_test_period";
    private final String C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS = "c3p0.max_statements";
    private final String C3P0_MAX_IDLE_TIME = "c3p0.max_idle_time";
    private final String C3P0_URL = "c3p0.url";
    private final String C3P0_USERNAME = "c3p0.username";
    private final String C3P0_PASSWORD = "c3p0.password";
    private final String C3P0_DRIVER_CLASSNAME = "c3p0.driverClassName";

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;


    @Bean
    Properties getHibernateProperties(){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        props.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        props.setProperty(SCHEMA_STRATEGY, environment.getProperty(SCHEMA_STRATEGY));
        props.setProperty(NEW_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS, environment.getProperty(NEW_GENERATOR_MAPPINGS));
        props.setProperty(IDENTIFIER_ROLLBACK, environment.getProperty(IDENTIFIER_ROLLBACK));
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws Exception {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean bean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.setPackagesToScan(BASE_PACKAGE);
        bean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        return bean;
    }



    @Bean
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(C3P0_MAX_SIZE)));
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(C3P0_MIN_SIZE)));
        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(C3P0_ACQUIRE_INCREMENT)));
        dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(C3P0_IDLE_TEST_PERIOD)));
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(C3P0_MAX_STATEMENTS)));
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(environment.getProperty(C3P0_MAX_IDLE_TIME)));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty(C3P0_URL));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(C3P0_PASSWORD));
        dataSource.setUser(environment.getProperty(C3P0_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getProperty(C3P0_DRIVER_CLASSNAME));
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

Giving

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) ~[spring-tx-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy135.getConfigurationValueByTypeAndKey(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.project.name.LoginView.prepareContent(LoginView.java:237) ~[web-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.project.name.LoginView.<init>(LoginView.java:36) ~[web-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.project.name.nameMain.goToLogin(nameMain.java:125) ~[web-3.0.jar:na]
    at com.project.name.HomeView$4.buttonClick(HomeView.java:84) ~[web-3.0.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1008) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:377) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:54) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:158) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118) ~[vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408) [vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273) [vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:79) [vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1409) [vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364) [vaadin-server-7.6.7.jar:7.6.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:281) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar:8.0.36]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.reset(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:130) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.<init>(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>(SessionImpl.java:258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1589) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.openSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:999) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:436) ~[spring-orm-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

If any information missing -- please tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add `@EnableTransactionManagement` anottation in your PersistenceConfiguration class.

And change transaction manager bean with this coide:

```
@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
}
```

Comment: thanks for response. Added 
@EnableTransactionManagement 
and changed transaction manager as you suggested, but still receiving same issue

Comment: I don't know if this will solve, but try remove the bean HibernateTemplate, its use is not recommended: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18002768/why-hibernatetemplate-isnt-recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the TransactionManager is not created, please check if all the relevant properties that you inject are being injected.